# Typo in Reversal Badge description

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges

While I'm writing this, the [**Reversal Badge**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/41/reversal) is described as

> Provid [*sic*] an answer of +20 score to a question of -5 score. This badge
>   can be awarded multiple times.

The first word is a misspelling of *Provide*.

Comment: It could also be *provided*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whoops.

Fixed in the next build.

Comment: Don't you mean fixd? ;)